# Momentum exerted on an external object by a Photon

Tags: forces, visible-light, photons, mass, solar-sails

I am trying to calculate momentum transferred by a **Photon** for **Solar Sails speed** (not exactly a photon because of wave-particle duality but i will consider it a Photon for this Question), So I had the following results: 2.998×10^-47  kilogram meters per second (with Rest Mass only)

I used [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) with Sir Newtons Second Law (p = mv) to Calculate it

Since light has no acceleration but velocity, I have calculated it's momentum so p=mv

I read on this [ScienceDirect](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.rinp.2019.102866) Article that Photons have are rest mass of 10 -54 kg

I did'nt find Relativistic Mass of A Photon with  ***780 Nanometer Wavelength Light***

I want to find out if my value is correct, how much would it differ with Relativistic Mass (Since i calculated it with rest mass)?

Can you please help me? I am new to equations

Comment: Probably best not to rely on data from a random paper on the internet whose first sentence starts "Some of the physical laws of nature are very peculiar ...".

Comment: link to your source?

Comment: The link for the Photon rest mass: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.rinp.2019.102866

Comment: Calculation AI: https://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: I thought photons were defined rest mass zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with photons it is better to think in terms of momentum rather than mass. A photon with frequency $\nu$ has momentum with magnitude $\frac {h \nu} c$. If the photon hits the light sail at an incident angle of $90$ degrees and if the light sail is perfectly reflective then the momentum of the photon is reversed, so the change in momentum of the photon is $2\frac {h \nu} c$. By conservation of momentum, the change in momentum of the light sail must also be $2\frac {h \nu} c$. If $N$ photons hit the light sail every second then the force exerted by the photons on the light sail is $2N\frac {h \nu} c$.

Comment: If the photon is reflected and maintains the same frequency (and therefore energy) as before it reflected, how did it impart energy on the sail?

Comment: Thanks, @gandalf61

Comment: @Matt:  The frequency of the reflected photon does shift downwards slightly;  you can show this by looking at conservation of four-momentum and solving for the final energy of the reflector and of the photon.  But in the limit where the mass-energy of the reflector is much greater than the mass-energy of the photon, we can approximate the photon's energy as nearly constant in the process.  It's very similar to a collision between a moving ping-pong ball and a bowling ball at rest:  the ping-pong ball does not lose very much energy when it bounces off.

Comment: As the internet is filled with confusing answers (and questions...) to/for this subject, and especially with regards to energy and momentum conservation between the photon and sail, I think it would help if @Matt 's question here in the comments was dealt with in the answer even if for practical calculations it's not relevant

Answer (score 0):

Answer by gandalf61 is correct. Another notable fact is that for light in general (and therefore for photons in particular) the relationship between energy $E$ and momentum $p$ is
$$
E = p c
$$
when the light is all propagating in the same direction (e.g. plane waves).
Therefore if you first calculate the energy in some light then you can get the momentum by dividing by $c$ (if the light is all going in the same direction).

Relating this to photons, we have for each photon $E = h f$ where $f$ is the frequency, and therefore $p = h f/c$ per photon. But you don't need to introduce photons. Just calculate the total energy arriving at the sail in some given time, and then use $p = E/c$. That's the momentum given to the sail if the energy is absorbed. If it is reflected then the total momentum change is $2E/c$.

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewSteane

Comment: The calculated result from 2E/c equation: 1.699×10^-27 joule seconds per meter

Comment: "If it is reflected then the total momentum change is 2E/c."  What  if the frequency thus energy does not change and the photon is Only reflected. Its solely change of direction would amount to a  change of momentum?

Comment: But the end result was in joules second. Does that mean the equations can also tell the angular momentum of heliogyro sails and spinning disc sails?